# /storage/emulated/0 obtained from getExternalCacheDir() generates "no such file or directory" error

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard

Running on a Nexus 4, when i call `getExternalCacheDir().getAbsolutePath()` i get as a path `/storage/emulated/0/Android/Data/com.example.myapp/cache`. The problem is that, as stated in different places, `/storage/emulated/0` generate a "no such file or directory" error.

What i expect to get is something like `/storage/emulated/legacy`, as i correctly get querying `EXTERNAL_STORAGE` environment variable with commands like `System.getenv("EXTERNAL_STORAGE")`.

I will just use a if statement to check and correct the path in case it will point to something different than what i get with `getenv`, but I want to understand why `getExternalCacheDir()` returns a invalid path, or if that function has been deprecated somehow.

Additional notes:
On Xperia U running CM11 works fine;
Targetting Nexus 4 with `adb` i get

```
ls /storage/emulated/0
/storage/emulated/0: No such file or directory
```

---

I've proper access permissions, since if I call, for example, `echo "hi!" >> /storage/emulated/legacy/Android/Data/com.example.myapp/cache` I have no clues, while calling `echo "hi!" >> /storage/emulated/0/Android/Data/com.example.myapp/cache` results in errors. The latter is what i get from `getExternalCacheDir`.

---

I'm interested in using that path with shell commands, not only with Android API functions.

Answer (score 0):

[getExternalCacheDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getExternalCacheDir()) gives you a valid path. 
You can read/write to it given your external storage is properly mounted and you have proper access permissions.

That is :

```
if (MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) // mounted
    && context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { // have permissions

    File myTempDir = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "tempDir");
    myTempDir.mkdirs();

    // create and write to files
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes, you are right, if used with `new File(getExternalCacheDir(), "tempDir");` it works like a charm!
The problem is that i need to use the Path with a shell command (ie. `ls`), so i need to get an absolutePath that is considered valid by the OS and not only by Android API

Comment: Please make sure that both 2 conditions stated in the answer : `MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()` and `context.checkCallingOrSelfPermission("android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED` are both true for your case with `.../emulated/0/...` path